# How can I extract a value from this simple JSON string in Excel VBA?

Tags: json, vba, excel

I have this simple json string in VBA :

```
{
    price_A: "0.172",
    price_B: "0.8",
    price_C: "1.3515"
}
```

I would like to **extract the value of `price_A` which is `0.172`**.

How can this be done in Excel VBA? I am using Microsoft Office 2013.

I don't need an extensive JSON library. Just a simple function to extract the value of `price_A`.

Comment: how do you store the string? is it a String? a varient? or something else?

Comment: The json is a string in VBA. The extracted value will be Single data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Regexp gives you more control on the parsing rather than relying on character length.

As an example:

```
Sub test_Function()
Dim StrIn As String

StrIn = "{" & _
    "price_A: " & Chr(34) & "0.182" & Chr(34) & "," & _
    "price_B: " & Chr(34) & "0.8" & Chr(34) & "," & _
    "price_C: " & Chr(34) & "1.3515" & Chr(34) & "}"

MsgBox Get_Value(StrIn)

End Sub
```

*extract first set of numbers in `""` after Price A*. Can be adapted to check for Price B

```
Public Function Get_Value(StrIn As String) As String  
Dim objRegexp As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Set objRegexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegexp
    .Pattern = "price_A: ""([\d\.]+)"""
    If .test(StrIn) Then
        Set objRegMC = .Execute(StrIn)
        Get_Value = objRegMC(0).submatches(0)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

*shorted version to extract first set of numbers*

```
Public Function Get_Value(StrIn As String) As String
Dim objRegexp As Object
Set objRegexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegexp
    .Pattern = "[\d\.]+"
    If .test(StrIn) Then Get_Value = .Execute(StrIn)(0)
End With
End Function
```